# Rails controller not correctly called on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

When I'm in development mode and try localhost:3000/documents/1 the view renders correctly and console displays:

```
Started GET "/documents/1" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by DocumentsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Document Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = 1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Document' ORDER BY created_at ASC, created_at DESC
  Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "document_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "document_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "document_tags"."document_id" = 1 AND "tags"."tag_family_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "document_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "document_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "document_tags"."document_id" = 1 AND "tags"."tag_family_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "document_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "document_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "document_tags"."document_id" = 1 AND "tags"."tag_family_id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "document_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "document_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "document_tags"."document_id" = 1 AND "tags"."tag_family_id" = 4 LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT name FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "document_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "document_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "document_tags"."document_id" = 1 AND "tags"."tag_family_id" = 5
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT name FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "document_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "document_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "document_tags"."document_id" = 1 AND "tags"."tag_family_id" = 6
  Rating Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 1 AND "ratings"."document_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered ratings/_show.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered comments/show.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered documents/show.html.erb within layouts/application (113.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_actions_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/sidebar/_reciente.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 159ms (Views: 138.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

But when I change to production I get:

```
    Started GET "/documents/1" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by DocumentsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (5.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Document Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Comment Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = 1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Document' ORDER BY created_at ASC, created_at DESC
  Rendered documents/show.html.erb within layouts/application (7.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 508ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass):
    13: <%if(!@tags.blank?) %>
    14:       <label>Palabras Clave:</label> <%=@tags.join(", ")%> <br />
    15: <%end%>
    16: <label>Un aporte de </label><%= link_to @uploader.username, user_path(@uploader)%>
    17: 
    18: <div id="ratings">
    19: <%= render :partial => 'ratings/show', :locals => {:model => @document} %>
  app/views/documents/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_documents_show_html_erb__1282539740_2502607180'
  app/controllers/roles_controller.rb:103:in `show'
```

And application trace shows:

```
    app/views/documents/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_documents_show_html_erb__1282539740_2502607180'
app/controllers/roles_controller.rb:103:in `show'
```

Why is the last line displaying roles_controller.rb:103:in `show' ? Shouldn't it be documents_controller.rb?
If I force the error in development by changing variable name to something that does not exist the error page shows in application trace:

```
    app/views/documents/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_documents_show_html_erb___1159141803_2474953060'
app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:29:in `show'
```

You can see that the last line shows documents_controller.rb.

I really don't know where to look. 
When I set config.cache_classes = true to false in production.rb the error disappears. (I do not know what this means).
Maybe I don't know how to configure routes. Should I post my routes.rb file?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just found out that roles_controllers had a partial definition of documents_controller and when cached in production it was the first one to be called. I just erased the partial definition of documents_controller in roles controller and moved everything to the correct controller.